# Is Feature/Scenerio a replacement for Describe/It?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I've been following the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). The author uses **Rspec/Capybara**'s `Describe/It` for the whole tutorial. But recently I've seen people using `Feature/Scenerio` instead. I wonder if `Feature/Scenerio` is a replacement of `Describe/It` or something that is used together? If it is a replacement, is there any reason of prefer it over `Describe/It`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question came up to me lately too. And I went to [Capybara's github page](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) to read more about it (search for *scenario*). Apparently *feature*, *scenario* and *background* are just aliases to make acceptance tests more readable. And I guess that's for legacy reasons -- cucumber uses those keywords. Therefore by aliasing them, capybara acceptance specs read more like traditional cucumber specs.

So no, feature/scenario/background are not a replacement of describe/it/before. As a group of methods, it is **only an alternative for acceptance specs**. It's up to you and your team to decide which ones to go with.